# Joomla Admin Missing Elements

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a Joomla site that I maintain and for some reason now when I log into the administrator section it looks like the below image.

I have tried all sorts of debugging but cannot seem to figure out what has happened.

There is no PHP errors. No JS errors. I have attempted to create a new user manually in the MySQL DB.

I am unsure if one of the other administrators of the site has performed an update and this has happened. I have manually updated the site to the latest version with no success.

[image: Missing Everything]

**EDIT**

Some Debugging Stats:

**Working Joomla! Site**

[image]

**Broken One**

[image]

It does not appear to even perform the database queries. (Still no errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons for this problem to happen:

- Errors on the Joomla website (perhaps caused by a non-core plugin). Try disabling non-core plugins (from phpMyAdmin) one by one and see if the problem is resolved.
- ACL issues caused by a wrong modification to your ACL

The first thing I would check is the ACL (in the database) and make sure that everything's correct.

Comment: Just had a look at all this...No success is resolving the issue. Would it be wise to "reinstall Joomla!"? i.e. download Full Package and reupload to FTP and overwrite all.

Comment: No - because the problem is most likely in the database. But you can always try to do it after backing up your website of course.

Comment: I enabled debugging on a working site to compare debugging info. (Posted images) It may be an issue with ACL. But I have checked this already, nothing is out of the ordinary.

Comment: OK! Finally got it sorted.

Issue was, someone messed with the Access Levels. As soon as I managed to change my login to the 'Administrator' group, as well as 'Super User' It all started working!

Changed the 'Access Levels' back to the right settings and all good now.